# What do you need to have a Cocos2d-x full backup?

Tags: backup, cocos2d-x

I have developers creating my app in Cocos2d-x, and I have asked them to send me a backup of the code in case their copy gets destroyed or I no longer want to work with them. I don't know what I should have in my possession that represents a full backup.

They sent me a .ipa file, but is that all I need to give to someone if I were to start over with a new programming team?

Comment: You need their entire project folder with sources. The ipa is the app store distribution file, you can not modify that.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I work with After Effects and need to give the assets with the project file itself.  Do you guys think it is that reasonable to demand that they send me the entire folder halfway through the project?

Comment: It really depends on the contract (terms) you have with the developers.